# In laravel when login after clearing session data it show the 419 expired error for first login but not second or third login

Tags: laravel, token

In laravel when i login after clearing session data it show the 419 expired error for first login  but not second or third. I have tired putting csrf field ,increase session time
also giving permission to the session folder but didn't work.I am using ubuntu 18.04, thank you

Comment: How are you clearing the session data? And is there a reason you do this?

Comment: Can you share your code? I guess you forget `return` somewhere in your code after clearing sesison.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Showing the community your code and the expected outcome is much more likely to yield answers for you. Good luck!

Comment: from chrome application->cookies->clear

Comment: i used defaut laravel login

Comment: i need to click login button twice to login sometimes it works sometimes it shows 419 expired which is very annoying..